# Can I create more than one association between two classes in a Class Diagram?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I have two classes: `User` and `Event`. 
The user can:

- Create an event.
- Comment on an event.

[image]

I want to know if I can create more than one association between event and user? Thank you for any references.

Answer (score 1):

You can create as many associations between classes as you need. There is no limit. You should add association-end names to clarify the purpose of each association, since without them the model will just not make much sense.

However, in your example you have one association class and a normal association. That *could* go without association ends.

Comment: The association end names are really important. Without them there are no properties to navigate across the association. UML does not generate default names for these (even though there *is* a non-normative sentence about this for the spec itself).

Comment: @JimL. Thanks for the correction. And yes, the names should not be left out since they add a lot of semantics to the model.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Thomas. You can create as many associations between classes as you need. You should also use association-end names to clarify your model and provide properties to navigate across the association.

Moreover, you should consider making a `Comment` a normal class in its own right, so you can add the semantics of *made by* one `User` and *made about* one `Event`. The way you have it modeled, you disallow multiple `Comments` from one `User` on one `Event`. Why would you want that?

Comment: Actually the `Comment` association class is just a class sitting between the two linked classes allowing to allow many relations.

Comment: It's not equivalent. The multiplicity from the other classes can have more specificity.

Comment: Uhm. I think the 1 at the User side here make this association class pointless. But generally an AC is a class sitting between 2 (or more) other classes establishing a n-m relation.

Comment: I don't understand your point. Do you agree that the assn class, as it is, makes it impossible to have multiple comments for the same event?

Comment: Yes. I agree. I was talking about assn  class in general. Seems we were cross talking again ;-)